# Is this an acceptable situation to store an array in a database?

Tags: mysql, arrays, database-design, multidimensional-array

I've been developing an application and I've run into a situation where I would like to take a **snapshot** of the current data.

For example, in this application, users will have varying stats and be able to enter matches. How they place in the matches depends on their stats. When the matches  are determined the application will pull all of the user's current stats and determine their points to see who wins.

Now after a match is over I want users to be able to view past matches and the problem arises when I want to display what the participants points were at the time of the match. I would think it would be acceptable to store an array structured like so:

```
array(
 array(username, points),
 array(username, points),
 etc.
)
```

Now normalizing the data may be the best practice normally but in this situation:

- There can be anywhere between **2** and **25** participants in a match.
- The data will never be updated, only read.
- I would think having it in an array structure in the database will save me time from having to construct an array in my back-end code.
- **EDIT: The data is not permanent. Match records will be deleted *7* days after the match has ended.**

Can anyone tell me if this solution will provide any problems?

---

### EDIT

I would be saving the data after serializing the array so in my database I would have a table called 'matches' and it would have a column called 'results'.

The rows for this column would contain serialized arrays. So if the array looked as such:

```
$array["a"] = "Foo";
$array["b"] = "Bar";
$array["c"] = "Baz";
$array["d"] = "Wom";
```

Then the row in the database would look like this:

```
a:4:{s:1:"a";s:3:"Foo";s:1:"b";s:3:"Bar";s:1:"c";s:3:"Baz";s:1:"d";s:3:"Wom";}
```

Comment: Well you could always serialize it but from my point of view I think it might be better to just come up with a better schema and keep your data normalized. just my two cents.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether you're talking about denormalizing the data, or actually storing a lump of data in a field. Can you provide an example of the table structure you're thinking of? Either way, I'm thinking that you're likely to get bitten somewhere down the road if you go this route. The extra work in coding a normalized structure will make it a heck of a lot easier to modify in the future.

Comment: @Ickster I've added the example you asked for.

Comment: you should read up on temporal databases (snodgras)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really committed to the use cases you've outlined in the question along with the qualification in your comment to Sean Johnson, then I don't see any problems with your approach.

I still might qualify that by suggesting that you normalize the data if you think there's a chance you'll want to be able to mine historical information, but dumping an array into the database as a long lived (relatively speaking) sort of cache might make sense. In other words, store it in both formats, but the main line of the use case you've outlined would just hit the array format, but you'd still have the data in a queryable form if you ever wanted it.

Comment: I may take this approach as I'm 99.9% sure that I won't be needing the data for anything other than what I've specified it would be used for. However it is hard telling how it the application will evolve over time. I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This solution wouldn't pose any problems in the short term - but say you wanted to eventually add in functionality to show all of the games a user has played in, or their highest scoring games... having this data in an inaccessible-from-sql array would not allow you to have those features.

I'm thinking a table like this would be perfect:

```
CREATE TABLE game_scores(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    game_id int,
    user_id int,
    final_score int,
    KEY(game_id),KEY(user_id)
)
```

At the end of every game, you'd simply insert a row for every user that was playing that round with their corresponding score and the game id. Later, you'd be able to select all of the scores for a certain game:

```
SELECT * FROM game_scores WHERE game_id=?
```

... or show all scores by a certain user:

```
SELECT * FROM game_scores WHERE user_id=?
```

etc. Have fun with it!

Comment: A good solution but I forgot to mention that matches will only be able to be viewed for up to 7 days after they've ended. This kind of defeats the purpose of designing the schema to account for this kind of functionality.

Comment: If it's temporary data, then I see no problem with just inserting the serialized data unless you want to be able to do things with the data other than just showing a score screen.

Comment: I'd also like to suggest using `json_encode` instead of `serialize`, json is not only smaller, it's much easier for us humans to read. :)